# How to create function for button

Tags: javascript, html

Im total begginer at programming. Just started today. I wanna learn Python really much. But im gonna start with html. So uhm i wanna create a function for my button. The function i want is for it to take me to an url. I have index.html and script.js.

Comment: I see that you are a new contributor to stackoverflow. I suggest that you visit stackoverflow  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  first. Its advised to stick to subject and provide code snippet (No one cares that you wanna learn python very much)

Comment: If a click on that button is suppose to take you to another url,  use a [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag instead.

Comment: You might want to just google around to learn and only come to stackoverflow to ask questions if you get stuck on something specific. Here's a view to try that may be helpful, I haven't watched it though and don't know what you're going for though so who knows.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30oWH6yKuB4

Answer (score 1):

You can nest a `<button>` in an `<a>` tag (which is a link) like so:

```
<a href="www.google.com"><button>Go to Google!</button></a>
```

You can replace the `www.google.com` with the URL that you want to go to.

Working example:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"><button>Go to Google!</button></a>
```

Or you can direction use JS like so with `location.replace`:

```
function goToGoogle(){
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Function working example:

```js
function goToGoogle(){
        window.location.replace("https://google.com");
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="goToGoogle()">Go to Google!</button>
```